# Help find a usb to ac cord

Tags: usb, ac, dc, charger

I've been looking every where for a cord that is powered by usb with an ac outlet on the other side so I can plug the usb into a portable battery and have an ac outlet can someone please tell me where to find this

Comment: Is there a reason you want a USB power bank rather than looking at a battery system designed to output AC power like a UPS? You are likely to get better answers if you describe what you want to power, as the amount of power most USB power banks can deliver is extremely limited compared to what a typical AC wall socket can deliver.

Comment: At the very least such a convertor would need active electronics to convert the 5V DC supply from the USB side into a 100-240V (whichever is appropriate for the outlet) AC supply.

Comment: you can get 5v to 12v boost cables, and then there's a huge range of 12v to AC inverters to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

The most power you might get from a usb outlet is 16 watts. So, converted to 110 volts a.c. with 99% efficiency, the most you would get out is 16 watts. Not even enough for a small soldering iron.
If you need portable power, consider something that uses a 12 volt battery, either lead acid or lithium ion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is such a product would have little practical use and would be a support nightmare.

A power-bank with a type A port is likely able to supply 1-2A at a nominal voltage 5V so a nominal 5W-10W. Lets say you lost 10% of that in the USB cable and another 20% in the inverter and the power brick of your device is also about 80% efficient. You have less than 6W usable for your device.

There just aren't many mains powered devices with a power consumption that low, and perhaps just as importantly a mains power socket doesn't have any mechanism for power negotiation.

There are power-banks with type C connectors that can supply more, but their output power limits are still often only 45W or 60W. You can charge a laptop off over USB C from such a power bank because the laptop and the power bank can negotiate a voltage and current that both are happy with, but if you put an inverter and a power brick in the path then as well as adding a bunch of inefficiency to the system you would be blocking the critical negotiation path that lets the laptop avoid drawing too much power and collapsing the supply.

To produce something that can meet the demands of a reasonably broad range of small electronics really needs an output power of at least 100W or so which means a DC input power of 125W or so, it's just not practical to get that over USB.

Answer (score 1):

Such a “cord” doesn’t exist and would be pointless anyway. A single USB battery bank provides too little power to be useful for almost anything besides powering a small 500mA USB charger… in which case you should just plug the thing in directly to the power bank.

The only way I’ve ever made this work in an emergency was to buy a bit over 20 power banks – all they had in stock at the gas station, insulating tape and a dozen cheap USB micro-micro cables. I cut the cables in half and connected the VBUS circuits in series, to yield about 105-120V out with all the banks plugged in, depending on the load. It was enough to push about 150W into a piece of test gear I had to use portably in a pinch. Yes, devices with switching power supplies, with no line-attached transformers, will run off DC no problem.

I do not suggest you do such a thing. The 5V regulation in each bank is a waste of energy in such an application.

Today one can buy battery banks used for emergency car starting that can put out about 12V directly. Only ten of those in series would be adequate – but one has to override their protection. The protection circuit limits the on-time making unmodified use impractical.

There are commercial lithium-battery UPS boxes and those would be a practical – if somewhat expensive – way of doing it safely.

Comment: There are also now larger power banks with built in inverters and AC outlets in various power ratings.

Comment: Yep. I’m waiting until gas station convenience stores will sell them as widely as they do USB power banks and USB cables :)